# Powershell - Searching XML node

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, how to search string pattern like below ?

```
        <PostSQL />
        <TableStyle>Quoted</TableStyle>
        <PreSQL />
        <TransactionMessages>False</TransactionMessages>
        <OutputOption>Overwrite</OutputOption>
```

I tried to put all the string into $SearchString variable, however it doesn't match. I believed this was due to line break in each of the string.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $InputLocation'\*' -Include $FileExtension -recurse | Select-String -pattern "$SearchString" | group path | 
select name | Out-File $OutputLocation'\'$OutputFile
```

Comment: Are you searching for something more specific that's better served by using `Select-Xml -XPath ...`?

Comment: Additionally, try breaking up part of your pipe into separate steps and variable assignments.  The transformation step where you `Select-String` and pipe the results into grouping by path looks like you're expecting files instead of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used with a file input `Select-String` seems to read the files line by line internally. We'll need to read the entire contents of each as *one string*, not an array of strings, and search it the usual way.

So, assuming this search string:

```
# the spaces are part of the match
$SearchString = @'
        <PostSQL />
        <TableStyle>Quoted</TableStyle>
        <PreSQL />
        <TransactionMessages>False</TransactionMessages>
        <OutputOption>Overwrite</OutputOption>
'@
```

use `Get-Content -raw` available since PowerShell 3.0:

```
Get-ChildItem "$InputLocation\*.xml" -recurse | Where {
    (Get-Content $_ -raw).Contains($SearchString)
}
```

or IO.File class for the older PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem "$InputLocation\*.xml" -recurse | Where {
    [IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName).Contains($SearchString)
}
```

We're using a literal string match, not a regexp, to speed up the search, so in case the spaces and line breaks in the search string need to be ignored, use a regexp and `-match` operator:

```
$rxSearch = $SearchString.Trim() -replace '>[\s\r\n]+<', '>[\s\r\n]*<'
Get-ChildItem "$InputLocation\*.xml" -recurse | Where {
    (Get-Content $_ -raw) -match $rxSearch
}
```

---

As for the further processing of the output, which is different from Select-String, pipe it to e.g. this:

```
| Group DirectoryName | Select -expand Group | Select -expand Name
```

Comment: Here the script but why Powershell prompt to supply values for the parameters ?                                                                          Get-ChildItem -Path $InputLocation'\*' -Include $FileExtension | Where {
    (Get-Content -raw) -match $rxSearch | Group DirectoryName | Select -expand Group | Select -expand Name | Out-File $OutputLocation'\'$OutputFile
}

Comment: I've updated the script but why output didn't print filename even though it matched ? 

Get-ChildItem -Path $InputLocation'\*' -Include $FileExtension | Where {
    (Get-Content $_ -raw) -match $rxSearch | Group path | Select name | Out-File $OutputLocation'\'$OutputFile
}

Comment: $SearchString = "
                <PostSQL />
                <TableStyle>Quoted</TableStyle>
                <PreSQL />
                <TransactionMessages>False</TransactionMessages>
                <OutputOption>Overwrite</OutputOption>"

Comment: $rxSearch = $SearchString.Trim() -replace '>[\s\r\n]+<', '>[\s\r\n]*<'

Comment: here the link for xml file https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlRIQ_Oswqe1pV6WVkk5wx2mWBCf

Comment: 1. Use DirectoryName instead of path 2. Correctly construct the pipeline: currently you've inserted `group .....` inside `Where`. Look at the correct structure: `gci | where { .... } | group .....`

Comment: I able to get the filename, but how to get full directory with filename together ?                                                                            Get-ChildItem $InputLocation'\*' -Include $FileExtension | Where {
    (Get-Content $_ -raw) -match $rxSearch} | Group DirectoryName | Select -expand Group | Select -expand name | Out-File $OutputLocation'\'$OutputFile

Comment: In that case `group` is not needed: `Where { ..... } | Select -expand FullName | Out-File ...`

Comment: Excellent !! Thanks